# Import the "thumbnail" of an internet page

Tags: import, internet

I have a list of internet sites links from which I would like to automatically recover the page image/thumbnail and page title.

Let's suppose that one of the links is https://www.google.com/, I would like to retrieve the following:

[image]

Is it possible to do it with *Mathematica*? Or maybe, managed by *Mathematica*?

Comment: Should the program also make typos? :P

Comment: @rm-rf Good one :) one more reason for wanting an automatic system...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
webShot[URI_String] := Import["http://www.sciweavers.org/iWeb2Shot?url=" <> URI]

webShot["google.com"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another one:

```
webShot["http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20486/import-the-thumbnail-of-an-internet"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: that easy? perfect! Now I need to add an automatic cut and resize.

Comment: You don't get my vote until you complete the [Droste effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droste_effect). (evil grin)

Comment: Oh my.  You did! +1